# AngularJS breaks on innerHTML edit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

I just came across a really curious issue while fiddling around.

I have created a logging function which appends the text to `document.body.innerHTML` like this.

```
function log(text)
{
   document.body.innerHTML += text + '<br>';
}
```

If I now call this funciton from my controller scope it breaks AngularJS.

Could someone explain this behaviour?

---

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/bq1ajd3t/) - click bar multiple times, they fire. click foo once, none of the click events work anymore

Comment: Because you are setting the `innerHTML`, you are effectively recreating the whole body element. The elements the controllers and directives are linked to are destroyed and your application will break. `document.body.innerHTML +=` is a bad idea in any scenario, but especially when using angular.

Comment: @Rhumborl could you write that as an answer, since this is definitely the correct and well explained answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are setting the `innerHTML`, you are effectively recreating the whole `<body>` element. The elements the controllers and directives are linked to are destroyed and your application will break (as will any vanilla JavaScript event handlers).

`document.body.innerHTML +=` is a bad idea in any scenario, but especially when using Angular.

If you need to do this, and cannot do it through standard Angular binding etc, a better option would be `angular.element(body).append()`

Answer (score 1):

you can't refer the body element `.innerHTML` inside the controller scope !

Answer (score 0):

**"Don't design your page, and then change it with DOM manipulations" - [Thinking in angularjs if I have a jquery background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).**

With angular, you put your event-binding in the view and don't do DOM manipulation in controllers. Here's the working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/81b2wb1w/).

**controller**

```
self.fooLog = [];

self.foo = function()
{
    self.fooLog.push("foo");
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in test.fooLog track by $index">
  {{foo}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, the thing is that I wanted a technical explanation why this happens (I've been developing in Angular for multiple years and just stumbled across this when prototyping something)