# I want to display multiple elements from a loop into the Document by its just showing the last element the user input instead showing everything

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

```
<body>
        <div id = "app">TODO... This is an HTML5 Template. Put your own content here.</div>
        <script>

        var Para = prompt("How many paragraph elements you want?");
        var  element;

        for(i = 0; i < Para; i++){
          element = prompt("Provide the element you want to fill up the Paragraph above");

        } 
        document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = element;
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: uses `element += '<p>'+prompt("Provide the element you want to fill up the Paragraph above")+'</p>'`

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something like this:

`document.getElementById("app").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', element);`

As stated by @Makyen, you shouldn't be using `innerHTML +=` as I stated in my first answer. That would probably create issues in your application, please follow the link in the comments to get more information.

And probably, the line of code I wrote should be inside the `for` loop.

```
for(i = 0; i < Para; i++){
  element = prompt("Provide the element you want to fill up the Paragraph above");
  document.getElementById("app").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', element);
}
```

Comment: @OscarAgbasi (&f-CJ) Using `.innerHTML +=` is *almost always* **bad**. Don't do it. Don't be in the habit of doing it. Here is some explanation: [In-page JavaScript stops when I use document.body.innerHTML += newHtmlText](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45215006) If you are going to do something like this then you should use [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). In this instance it would be `appElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', element)`. Note: you should do `document.getElementById("app")` only once and store it into a variable.

Comment: Thanks @Makyen, I was not aware of that. I edited my answer, cheers.