# How to display html tag in string?

Tags: javascript, html

There is a requirement that retrieving some msg including HTML tag from the back-end, how to rightly display HTML tag but not original tag character.

msg like below ( displays in quotation marks ) :

```
"This is a <a href="#">link</a>, for a test."
```

right display:

"This is a [link](https://www.google.com), for a test."

Comment: Can you please show the snippet.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You have to bypass or escape the special characters.Here it is double quotes. Add a slash \ before it and you should be fine.

Comment: What did you try? What gone wrong?

Comment: @Francisaskquestion to attain what? There is simply no way to attain what it is to be attained. Proof: you are the only one who understood they wanted to keep the markup unparsed.

Comment: Wrong thread.......

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want display string as `html`. You just need to add it as `innerHTML`. Not `innerText` or `textContent`

#### Wrong Display

```js
let str = `This is a <a href="#">link</a>, for a test.`
document.body.innerText += str;
```

#### Right Display

```js
let str = `This is a <a href="#">link</a>, for a test.`
document.body.innerHTML += str;
```

If you want quotes around string use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
let str = `"This is a <a href="#">link</a>, for a test."`
document.body.innerHTML += str;
```

Comment: "*from the backend*" templates are useless.

Comment: @Kaiido He can just interpolate that string from backend to inside template literals

Comment: Ah.. that's how you interpreted this. For me it was coming from an AJAX request => already a string, no need for templates. But I now realize this question is even less clear than I first though.

Comment: Using `document.body.innerHTML += str` is a terrible way to add something to the DOM. It will often cause the JavaScript that works with the page to stop working, as it destroys the current DOM and recreates it. If you want to append some HTML text to the `document.body` then you should use [`document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). If you want more information, see [In-page JavaScript stops when I use document.body.innerHTML += newHtmlText](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45215006/3773011).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `innerHTML` for this.

Example:

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML  = yourTextWithHtml
```

Comment: Where did he mentioned that he is not using `innerHTML`

Comment: _You should use `innerHTML` for this_. How do you know he is not using innerHTML

Comment: Nothing bro have fun

Answer (score 0):

**You can render HTML using document.write()**

```
document.write(`This is a <a href="#">link</a>, for a test.`);`
```

But to append existing HTML string, you need to get the id of the node/tag under which you want to insert your HTML string.

There are two ways by which you can possibly achieve this:

**Using DOM -**

```
var tag_id = document.getElementById('tagid'); 
var newNode = document.createElement('p');
newNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`This is a <a href="#">link</a>, for a test.`)); 
node.appendChild(newNode);
```

**Using innerHTML -**

```
var tag_id = document.getElementById('tagid'); 
tag_id.innerHTML(`This is a <a href="#">link</a>, for a test.`);
```

Also You can use jQuery html parser to do that like this:

```
var html =  `This is a <a href="#">link</a>, for a test.`;
html = $.parseHTML( html);
$("#tagId").append(html);
```

I hope this would help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Escaping -**

You should escape any quotes found within your string. Place the `\` in front of them to escape.

```js
console.log("This is my string with quotes \" \" ")
```