# Outputting an object to a page that keeps close function

Tags: javascript, html

I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814303/prepend-output-to-div-with-javascript-no-jquery-and-a-couple-other-questions) before, among others. But it was suggested I need to ask a more specific or focused question.

I am working on an output history log on a single page. And I want to make it so each output it's self is contained in box object that can be closed or deleted individually. Like [this.](https://jsfiddle.net/CodingGuy1984/vmehkuy3/1/)

Now I have managed to get everything working to the point where it will nicely output to a box with a close button. However the close button it's self will not function in this case.

So, I am trying to output it like this...

HTML:

```
<p>History log:</p><br><div style="white-space:pre-wrap"><ul 
id="outputListItem" class="boxcontainer"></ul></div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
document.getElementById("Add").onclick = function(e) {
convertOutput();
}

function convertOutput(){
//this is the part I have been trying to get working
convertOutput.addEventListener('close', function() {
this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
});

var output = document.getElementById("output").value;
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.className = "containedboxes";
var dateTime = todayDateTime();

li.innerHTML = "<time id='time'>" + dateTime +"</time><br /> <br />"+ output 
+"<br /><br /><span class='close'>&times;</span>";
   document.getElementById('outputListItem').prepend(li);
}
```

And the script to close the box:

```
var closebtns = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < closebtns.length; i++) {
closebtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
});
}
```

It was suggested to me on the last question I posed I should  use convertOutput() right after addEventListener() loop immediately after it. If this is how you do it, i am still quite new to JavaScript, so not sore how to properly do this. I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CodingGuy1984/a7nh4sgc/7/) for this also, but for some reason I can't get the script to run properly in the fiddle, But all the code is there to see.

I am looking to solve this using vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Don't write "NO JQUERY" in your question titles. Tag your question with `javascript` and simply don't use the `jquery` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an example for you. Hopefully this helps you get going :) A couple things to note, I use a data attribute to store the index for the item in the array, so you can delete it when you click on the list item.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 let nameEl = document.querySelector("#name");
 let submitEl = document.querySelector("#submit-name");
 let historyEl = document.querySelector(".history-list");

 let historyList = [
  { name: 'Mitch'},
  { name: 'Max'},
  { name: 'Mike'},
 ];

 function addToList(arr) {
  // Clear up list and then update it
  while(historyEl.firstChild) {
   historyEl.removeChild(historyEl.firstChild);
  }
  // Update the list with the historyList
  for(let item in historyList) {
   let name = historyList[item].name;
   let listContent = document.createElement("li");
   listContent.textContent = name;
   // We will use the index to remove items from the list
   listContent.setAttribute('data-value', item);
   listContent.addEventListener("click", removeFromList)
   historyEl.appendChild(listContent);
  }
 }

 function removeFromList(index) {
  // Takes the index of the object, and will later remove it
  console.log("Removed Item " + this.dataset.value);
  historyList.splice(index, 1);
  addToList(historyList);

 }

 addToList(historyList);

 submitEl.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if(nameEl.value) {
   // Add the name to the start of the history list array.
   historyList.unshift({ name: nameEl.value})
   nameEl.value = '';
   // Update the dom with the new array
   addToList(historyList);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<label for="name">Type Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<button id="submit-name">Submit Name</button>

<ul class="history-list"></ul>
```

Hopefully this gives you a good idea on how to get the task done and let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: No problem, and have fun with the project :)

Answer (score 1):

Your boxes don't respond to the click event simply because your script crashes before the events even get attached to it.
The following block right at the beginning:

```
document.getElementById("Add").onclick = function(e) {
convertOutput();
}
```

tries to add a click listener to the HTML element **Add** which does not exist. If you either remove the code block or add the appropriate element your boxes will have it's click functionality.